# Finnish Permanent residence permit to use in Sweden

Tags: resident-permit, eu, working, sweden, finland

I have a Finnish permenant residence permit. I intend to go to live and work in Sweden. For that purpose I have contacted the Swedish immigration office. They informed me that in order to have a right to work in Sweden these letters (`P EY 2003/109 EY`) should exist on my Finnish residence permit card. Then I am allowed to work in Sweden. Now I wonder what kind of application could be used for this kind of residence permit? l have searched and called around a lot, but l have not got any suitable reply so far from Migri or anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I believe they are mentioning that you must have your permanent residence granted under the EU rules, rather than Finnish rules.

**EU Long Term Residence** rather than Permanent Residence.